# Ruby 1.9.2 + Rails 3.0.3 + postgresql + windows vista

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-vista, ruby-1.9.2

I would like to install Ruby1.9.2/Rails3.0.3 on my Windows Vista machine with PostgreSQL 9.0 as my database.

I have seen many different instructions on the web as to what works and what does not work.

Can anybody tell me which gem(s) I must install to get Ruby1.9.2/Rails 3.0.3 to drive PostgreSQL 9.0 on Windows Vista?

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: This might not be what you want to hear, but I'd strongly recommend you just install ubuntu in a virtual machine and run ruby off of that. Ruby and Rails just aren't developed with Windows in mind. You will hit speedbump after speedbump.

Comment: @ryeguy - Given that this question has had over 200 views, I think that there might be a demand for a solution here.

Answer (score 6):

I made a how-to for exactly this topic on:

http://netpie.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/setting-up-rails-3-with-postgresql-on-windows/

Please let me know if it worked for you and tell me where you had problems so that I can improve this how-to.

Best regards

Comment: That is excellent. I can't believe that somebody hasn't done this up until now. I'm going to try it out this weekend (Mar 26-27, 2011) and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get the Ruby 1.9.2 installer

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167

Just click on it and it does all the work, after that go for Rails

Rails is easy, just download and follow the site instructions

http://rubyonrails.org/

About PostGre, you are on your own because I never used it...

But if you follow the instructions on the Rails web site you should be fine, they point the right ways to connect to several DBs

Comment: I got that far too and I have Ruby 1.9.2/Rails 3.0.3 running fine on my Vista machine with SQLite as the database. I checked various sources for instructions on how to configure Postgres, but many were out of date, and meant for Rails 2 or Ruby 1.8.x.